# WPF exception while binding combobox to linq2sql

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, combobox, binding

I have a ComboBox:

```
 <ComboBox Name="cmbSuppliers" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="30"></ComboBox>
```

When trying to bind it in this method:

```
public void BindSuppliers()
    {
        using (ScanFlowDataClassesDataContext db = new ScanFlowDataClassesDataContext(GlobalConfig.connectionString))
        {
            var suppliers = from s in db.Suppliers
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = s.Id,
                            Name = s.Name,
                        };
            cmbSuppliers.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
            cmbSuppliers.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
            cmbSuppliers.ItemsSource = db.Suppliers.Select(s => s).OrderBy(s => s.Name);
        }
    }
```

I get exception (on the last line) saying: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

Please help me solve this!

Comment: `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` in XAML seems redundant when you later set the ItemsSource property in code behind. Besides that, `db.Suppliers.Select(s => s)` doesn't seem to make sense. Do you probably just wanted to write `cmbSuppliers.ItemsSource = suppliers.OrderBy(s => s.Name);`?

Comment: Assuming db object is EntityFramework datacontext object. Always db context from EntityFrameWork will return IQueryable. So you to convert it to List like this cmbSuppliers.ItemsSource = db.Suppliers.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbSuppliers" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Height="30">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item2} />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Method:

```
public void BindSuppliers()
    {
        using (ScanFlowDataClassesDataContext db = new ScanFlowDataClassesDataContext(GlobalConfig.connectionString))
    {
        var suppliers = from s in db.Suppliers
            select new Tuple<int,string>(s.Id, s.Name);
        cmbSuppliers.DisplayMemberPath = "Item2";
        cmbSuppliers.SelectedValuePath = "Item1";
        cmbSuppliers.ItemsSource = suppliers.OrderBy(s => s.Item2);
    }
}
```